# mysql query return zero row

Tags: mysql, zero

here is my query which is searching the  student from data base with name or phone number.

```
select ct.id, c.name as batchname,ct.qualification,ct.fees,ct.email,
       ct.email,ct.phone, ct.name, ct.status,ct.notification 
from student ct , batch c 
where ct.batch_id=c.id and c.status=1 
      and (ct.name like '%Aniruddha%' or ct.phone like '%Aniruddha%')
```

the problem is it will fetching the zero row form database if the student is
present in the database. what is the error in query i cannot identify please
anyone can help.

Comment: Is `ct.phone like '%Aniruddha%' ` correct??

Comment: check for batch_id values in student table. this wouldn't return anything if that field is null.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
select ct.id, c.name as batchname,ct.qualification,ct.fees,ct.email,
       ct.email,ct.phone, ct.name, ct.status,ct.notification 
from student ct 
left join batch c on ct.batch_id=c.id
where c.status=1 
      and (ct.name like '%Aniruddha%' or ct.phone like '%Aniruddha%')
```